# Mesh jumps after adding edge loops while weight painting v2.79

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I was working on a hand mesh rig and discovered that the mesh did not have enough topology at the joints for a smooth deform. I added some edge loops at the joints to give me more to work with.[image: Mesh with bones in edit mode]
[image: Vertex weights that were added by selecting the vertices and manually assigning a weight]
Now whenever I modify the weights by either adding or subtracting weight, the modified vertices will jump about half a blender unit along the -y axis to its original location even though it still has weight.
[image: The result from adding weight to the joint]
Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: This kind of extreme deformation can be caused by being accidentally weighted to some other, distant bone. Cycle through the vertex groups to see if there are any that are incorrectly assigned. Also check that the names of your bones are correctly mirrored from right to left (same name, but with a ".R" or ".L" appended): a mirror modifier mirrors weights by default which can give weird results when the bones are incorrectly named

Comment: Ill double check, but before I posted this I had taken all the vertexes away from the hand vertex groups and used the "Show Zero Weights:All" option to see if they were in any other group, and they seemed not to be. I have named all off center bones with .R and .L extensions, and I'm not using the mirror modifier for either the mesh or armature right now. To keep my painting similar across both sides I'm using X-mirror in the weight painting tools.

Comment: Could you post the blend file so I can take a look at it?

Comment: Here is a link to the zip: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkInFA2unOTq80hATyiNQm6Xes-0